# iOS binding project builds but not usable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, binding

I have been working on creating a binding project for an iOS SDK for the last week or so. I have gone through the steps in the Xamarin Developer guides walkthrough, I created the .a library on the Mac and ran the sharpie tool to create ApiDefinitions and Structs. I then created the binding project and put the library and code from the ApiDefinitions and Structs into the relevant files. I got a lot of error messages which I have worked through and solved so the project now builds successfully.

My issue is that I can't seem to do anything with the project now. When I look at it in Visual Studio Object Browser no classes appear below it. I can reference it in an iOS project but I can't seem to use it within a class.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on what could be wrong. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,
Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

To help you objective-sharpie commandline will be needed (what you used). Some libraries have no umbrella header file (in that case I create those manually) and sharpie cannot find c/objc declarations to surface API.

There are additional options that can be passed to clang from sharpie commandline (not trivial).

Anyway more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Moljac,
The sharpie command I am using is:
sharpie bind --output=BrightcoveIos --namespace=BrightcoveSDK --scope=./Brightcove.Ios/ --sdk=iphoneod11.2 ./BrightcoveIos/BrightcovePlayerSDK.h
where ./Brightcove.Ios/ is the folder holding all of the .h files and BrightcovePlayerSDK.h is the main file calling all of the others.  BrightcovePlayerSDK.h starts like this:

`// BrightcovePlayerSDK.h`

`//BrightcovePlayerSDK`

`// Copyright (c) 2018 Brightcove, Inc. All rights reserved.`

`// License: https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions`

`#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

`FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char BrightcovePlayerSDKVersionString[];`

`#import "BCOVPlaybackService.h"`

`#import "BCOVPlaybackServiceRequestFactory.h"`

`#import "NSDictionary+BCOVURLSupport.h"`

`#import "BCOVPlayerSDKManager.h"`

`#import "BCOVBasicSessionProvider.h"`

`#import "BCOVCuePointProgressPolicy.h"`

etc.

I'm not sure if that highlights any issues?

Thanks,
Stephen.